# Installing and configuring Snort, Barnyard2 on ubuntu 13.10 in AWS EC2 VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws, snort

I need you help after searching a whole lot and asking AWS my problem is not getting resolved, so I have come here for your help.

I have a AWS VPC setup with all ubuntu servers

I have a NAT server created which has Snort and Barnyard installed, I followed the following guide 
[Snort, Barnyard2, PulledPork and Aanval](http://wiki.aanval.com/wiki/Community%3aSnort_2.9.2.3_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu_12.04,_with_Barnyard2,_Pulledpork,_and_Aanval#Preparation)

The versions used for Snort and Barnyard are the latest and not from the guide.

using the following command shows that the data is getting sniffed over the network

`tcpflow -i eth0 -C -e port 80`

The problem is there are no events being created in the DB and I am unable to test if Snort is functioning properly

The commands used for Snort is

`/usr/sbin/snort -A fast -b -d -D -i eth0 -u snort -g snort -c /usr/local/snort/etc/snort.conf -l /var/log/snort/eth0`

The command used for Barnyard is

`barnyard2 -D -c /etc/snort/barnyard.conf -d /var/log/snort/eth0 -w /var/log/snort/eth0/barnyard2.waldo -l /var/log/snort/eth0 -a /var/log/snort/eth0/archive -f snort.log -X /var/lock/barnyard2-eth0.pid`

Please guys help me with this. I thank you guys in advance.

P.S. I am really new to SNORT and Barnyard2 please guide me step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you upgraded to 14.04
I am new too
I only have a few guides, to share

- http://sathisharthars.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/configuring-snort-with-barnyard-snortreport-acid-in-ubuntu-14-04/
- http://www.rivy.org/technologies/snort/